# Python applying function over each column of the array

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use the function InterpolatedUnivariateSpline as:

```
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
B = np.array([11,34,56,78,19])
C = np.random.normal(0, 1, (500, 30))
model = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(A, B, k = 1)
C2 = model(C) #fails with error object too deep for desired array
C2 = model(C[:,0]) #works but is not useful as I need inter-/extra-polation for entire C
```

So, how do I apply the function to all elements of array C

Edit: scipy version: 0.13.2

Comment: `C2 = model(C)` works for me. What version of `scipy` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could just use list comprehension:

```
C2 = [model(i) for i in C]
```

It will run "model" on all elements and return the list

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your `scipy` to version 0.16.1 and it will work for your multi-dimensional array, i.e:

```
C2 = model(C)
```

works.